# How can I access/call array(list) data from another class in Flutter?

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, dart

Example i have three dart class.
`main.dart`, `firstdata.dart`, and `seconddata.dart`.

then in `firstdata.dart` and `seconddata.dart` i have list/array data

`firstdata.dart`:

```
class firstdata{
 static logo = [ assets/pic1.png, assets/pic2.png];
 static name = [ 'dani', 'lict'];}
```

`seconddata.dart`:

```
class seconddata{
 static logo = [ 'assets/image1.png', 'assets/image2.png'];
 static name = [ 'rose', 'fanny'];}
```

Question: How can i call/access array/list value from `firstdata.dart` and `seconddata.dart` to `main.dart`?

Answer (score 2):

```
//Custom class in project directory
class FirstData {
 FirstData._();
 static logo = [ assets/pic1.png, assets/pic2.png];
 static name = [ 'dani', 'lict'];
}

class SecondData {
 SecondData._();
 static logo = [ assets/image1.png, assets/image2.png];
 static name = [ 'rose', 'fanny'];
}
```

And Now Call Like this any class like:

```
class MainClass {
 // From Class Second
 FirstData.logo;
 FirstData.name;

 // From Class Second
 SecondData.logo;
 SecondData.name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly access all the static variable using class name only.

```
void main() {
    print(Firstdata.logo);
}

class Firstdata{
 static var logo = ['logo'];
 static var name = [ 'dani', 'lict'];}

class Seconddata{
 static var logo = [ 'assets/image1.png, assets/image2.png'];
 static var name = [ 'rose', 'fanny'];}
```

Comment: Accept the answer if you found useful @SDi

Comment: what if Firstdata class is Stateful?